# the sequence of derivative cannot satisfy $|f^{(n)}(z_0)| > n!n^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$. Prove that for any $z_0 \in \Omega$, the sequence of derivatives cannot satisfy $|f^{(n)}(z_0)| > n!n^n$

In this problem, I intend to prove by contradiction, and I tried to use Cauchy's estimate theorem; but, it leads to nowhere. Any help would be great. Thank you

Comment: You should probably point out that $f$ is analytic.

Comment: sorry, that's all the information that I have. Probably, I should assume that $f$ is analytic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f$ is analytic at $z_0$, we write
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}(z-z_0)^n
$$
in some open disc $U\ni z_0$ of radius $r>0$.
If $|f^{(n)}(z_0)|>n!n^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then
$
|a_n|>n^n
$ and so
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}>\limsup_{n\to\infty}n=\infty
$$
By Hadamard's formula, the radius of convergence of this series is therefore $0$, contradicting the fact that the power series expansion of $f(z)$ is valid in all of $U$.